# Is it possible to set ctrl+alt+del to unlock?

Tags: shortcut-keys, lock-screen

On Windows I have a setting enabled so that when the PC is locked, I have to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> to get to the login screen instead of just pressing any key. Is there a way I can set this (or similar) up in Ubuntu?

Comment: This complication may not be available in Ubuntu. The security is made up by the user's password, not by having to press that key combination.

Comment: @vanadium Thanks.